# Finding a MongoDB document by different types with Mongoskin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoskin

This is an example of document that I have in my MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('5525039895884d66710d0fc3'),
    "prid": "63527",
    "data": {
        "sku": "HF22-81639",
        "name": "Product Test",
        "ean": "8763900872512",
        "description": "This product is my first test",
    }
}
```

I want to make several search methods, where the search criteria are search by SKU, EAN or PRID. I created the methods but do not work, this is the example of one of the methods that I created and it does not work, just find the first document of my database but without any search criteria.

This search for "_id" if it works perfectly:

```
// GET - "_id"
app.get("/:id", function(req, res, next) {
    req.collection.findOne({
        _id: id(req.params.id)
    }, function(e, result) {
        if(e) return next(e);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

This search for "sku" does not work (this is where I need help):

```
// GET - "sku"
app.get("/sku/:id", function(req, res, next) {
    req.collection.findOne({
        sku: id(req.params.sku)
    }, function(e, result) {
        if(e) return next(e);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how your `id()` function is defined but you could try:

```
// GET - "sku"
app.get("/sku/:id", function(req, res, next) {
    req.collection.findOne({
        "data.sku": req.params.id
    }, function(e, result) {
        if(e) return next(e);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

In your original code, `req.params.sku` is undefined because the `req.params` object doesn't have the field `sku`. From the url, only the `req.param.id` field is defined (from this => `"/sku/:id"`). So for example, if you test your API with this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/sku/HF22-81639
```

will bring back the document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('5525039895884d66710d0fc3'),
    "prid": "63527",
    "data": {
        "sku": "HF22-81639",
        "name": "Product Test",
        "ean": "8763900872512",
        "description": "This product is my first test",
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the best solution!! But, I have a question, if I have a field that is description, and I want to look up a word in the text in each product? How would it be?

Comment: @Despotars Can you be a bit more clearer please? An example would be nice. From how I understood it, do you mean, say for instance, you want to search the collection for documents where the description field contains the product name, e.g `db.collection.findOne({"data.description": /productname/i})`?

Comment: yes sorry. For example looking for all the products they have in their description the word "park."And send the word as in the above example I send the sku

Comment: @Despotars Can you please create another question for this since it would would be pretty noisy to answer in comments? I can't edit the my answer to accommodate this because it's a different question.

Comment: this is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517065/finding-a-mongodb-document-through-a-word-in-a-field-description-in-each-product