# Finding a MongoDB document through a word in a field description in each product with Mongoskin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoskin

This is an example of document that I have in my MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('5525039895884d66710d0fc3'),
    "prid": "63527",
    "data": {
        "sku": "HF22-81639",
        "name": "Product Test",
        "ean": "8763900872512",
        "description": "This product is my first test",
    }
}
```

This search for "description" does not work (this is where I need help):

```
app.get("/description/:id", auth, function(req, res, next) {
    req.collection.findOne({
        "data.description": req.params.id
    }, function(e, result) {
        if(e) return next(e);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

I need to find through a word, all the products that exist in the collection include in the description field that word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find through a word, all the products that exist in the collection include in the description field that word, you need a regex match  with case insensitivity. You could use the following query (as an example):

```
db.product.find({"data.description": /test/i});
```

where the `i` in the `/test/i` indicates case insensitivity, thus the regex matches on the description field for any text with the string `"test"`. The equivalent SQL expression follows:

```
select * from product where description like '%test%'
```

So you could use the same in your route implementation, using the [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) method to return all matched documents instead of the [**`findOne()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#db.collection.findOne) which returns just one document:

```
app.get("/description/:id", auth, function(req, res, next) {
    req.collection.find({
        "data.description": /req.params.id/i
    }, function(e, result) {
        if(e) return next(e);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Another option is to use the [**`$text`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) operator in your find operation as it performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index. So the first thing you would do is create a text index on the description field:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "data.description": "text" } )
```

After that you can query using the $text operator. For example, the following query searches for the term coffee:

```
db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee" } } )
```

**EDIT**:

All things being equal, you can then update your route implementation to use query strings in the URL instead:

```
app.get("/description", auth, function(req, res, next) {
    req.collection.find({
        $text: { $search: req.params.q }
    }, function(e, result) {
        if(e) return next(e);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

which you can query in your browser as `http://localhost/description?q=product`

Comment: I have a little question. I used the second option. Why does this code do not work? If I make a call from the console mongodb like this> db.itemData.find ({$ text: {$ search: "product"}}) The system finds my product, but if I do calling search method does not work (http://localhost/description/product), what can be due?

Comment: @Despotars You could use query string instead, I have updated the answer to include this; `http://localhost/description?q=product`

Comment: I used this: http://localhost:3000/description?q=coffe and I have received this: "Response does not contain any data" but, if I whrite this sentence in mongo terminal, I received the document. Why it is this possible?

Comment: @Despotars Once again, I would encourage you to open a new question for this as it rather becomes nosiy if we continue to update the answer with each new problem that comes along.

Comment: But this is the same question, right? I used this code but I didn't receive the document, Do you think I need open a new question for this problem?